# A question about difference of maximum principle from two different book

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Let assume
$$Lu=Au+a(x)u=f(x)$$ 
Where $A$ is elliptic operator.

In Chapter 8 of Smoller book the maximum principle is as follow:
[image]

On the other hand, the maximum principle of Han-Lin book says: (note that $a(x)$ is replaced by $c(x)$ in this book)
The second [image]

The first one says positive maximum and the second one says nonnegative maximum. I can't understand this difference .

For example if I want to show that the solution of the following problem
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u -2u=e^u & \Omega \\
u=0 & \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$ 
is strictly negative in $\Omega$. The second one works but the first one seems not to work and only says that it has no negative minimum, which means solution is nonpositive.

Comment: _Which_ maximum principle is Smoller discussing (strong, weak, Hopf)?

Comment: @ Mattos: I have uploaded the screen shot. I think if replace the negative minimum with nonpositive minumum then it is strong maximum principle.